# New frame with scratch (text-mode) -- close, but no cigar . .

Tags: emacs, elisp

The following code only generates the new buffer in fundamental mode, and I haven't been able to figure out how to get the new scratch buffer to automatically generate in text mode . . .   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```lisp
(setq initial-major-mode 'text-mode)

(defun new-frame-with-scratch ()
  "Open a new frame with scratch buffer selected"
  (interactive)
  (let ((frame (make-frame)))
    (select-frame-set-input-focus frame)
    (if (get-buffer-create "*lawlist*" )
        (switch-to-buffer "*lawlist*" 'norecord))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initial-major-mode` is only used when creating the initial `*scratch*` buffer, so I think it won't help you there. You have to explicitly change mode in your newly created `*lawlist*` buffer:

```lisp
(defun new-frame-with-scratch ()
  "Open a new frame with scratch buffer selected"
  (interactive)
  (let ((frame (make-frame))
        (scratch-name "*lawlist*"))
    (select-frame-set-input-focus frame)
    (unless (get-buffer scratch-name)
      (with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create scratch-name)
        (text-mode)))
    (switch-to-buffer scratch-name 'norecord)))
```

The logic can be made simpler if you want to unconditionnally set your `*lawlist*` buffer to `text-mode` each time `new-frame-with-scratch` is called.

Comment: AWESOME -- Thank you so very much!  I had previously tried inserting `(text-mode)` at various portions of the snippet, but didn't get it right.  Your modification works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

You can simply remove your `(if (get-buffer-create "*lawlist*" )` since `switch-to-buffer` will create the buffer if it doesn't exist yet, and if it creates it, then it calls `set-buffer-major-mode`.  But note that `initial-major-mode` only applies to the buffer named `*scratch*`, you should instead `(setq-default major-mode 'text-mode)`.  Easier is to explicitly call the major-mode you want, as in the solution proposed by Francesco.

Comment: I wish I could check off both correct answers -- your help is greatly appreciated.  I have added to my init.el file:  `(setq-default major-mode 'text-mode)`.